# Как через .htaccess запретить прямой доступ к файлу, но разрешить его использование через ajax?

Tags: .htaccess

Как через .htaccess запретить прямой доступ к файлу, но разрешить его использование через ajax?

Comment: никак. "использование через ajax" это тоже "прямой доступ".

Comment: В WordPress файл обработки ajax должен проверяеть наличие nonce, которое генерируется на стороне сервера. При отсутствии или несовпадении nonce выполнение файла прекращается.